# Extracting and adding multiple values from json in jmeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I am extracting multiple values from json reponse using json extractor. My goal is to add all these value. I have tried using foreach controller but it does not work for me.

[image]

I have a debug samples confirming I am retrieving all the values. I need to get the some of all these values. The values can range from 0 to several thousands. Is there an easy way to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a JSON structure like this

```
{
    "body": [
        { "count": 0 },
        { "count": 23 },
        { "count": -1 },
        { "count": 20 },
        { "no_count_here": "really" }
    ]
}
```

Then your Post Processor will add a variable named `countFromResponse` with the content `0,23,-1,20`. To sum these values up, you have to split the string at each comma, convert the string snippets to Integer values and sum them all up and convert it back to a string. That value can then be stored in another variable named `countFromResponse_SUM`.

This can be accomplished using a JSR223 Post Processor, that uses the following groovy code:

```
overall = vars.get("countFromResponse_ALL")
    .split(",")
    .collect { Integer.valueOf(it) }
    .sum()
    .toString()
vars.put("countFromResponse_SUM", overall)
```

The conversion back to string is important, as all normal variables in JMeter will be treated as strings.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.